# Is Faroq/Blackout dead?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

TV Tropes claims this character didn't survive the episode (and it did look that way) but at the end of the episode he (or his body) is shown to be kept in a cell in the pipeline- what would be served by locking up a dead man?

Comment: They're not just locking up the body of a dead man, they're locking up the body of a dead metahuman. They don't know for sure what may happen to the body after death, and they need to keep it safe from the public.

Comment: Also, it's implied that Wells is very interested in Blackout's ability to drain the Flash's power.

Comment: Does that mean that Clyde and Danton from the previous episodes are also locked down in the pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

#### Faroq is indeed, quite dead. But his metahuman ability of absorbing the energy of the Flash, draining in particular his connection to the Speed Force appears to be of great interest to Dr. Wells/Reverse Flash.

- Given his knowledge of future technology, he may believe it could instrumental in harnessing more of the Speed Force and returning to the future, which he currently appears to be too slow to be able to do.
- I suspect he is keeping Faroq in the equivalent of a [morgue drawer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgue), keeping him on ice until he can figure out how to reverse-engineer his metahuman draining ability.

Comment: One nitpick - It's a show based on a comic book. There's no guarantee that ANYBODY will stay dead.

Comment: As a long time reader of comics, I am absolutely sure there will be a way, if readers/viewers/producers demand it, Faroq can and will be returned to life. I merely answered the OP's question. In comics unlike real life, Death has a revolving door with opportunities to return to the Game of Life ready for those tampering with forces beyond their understanding (such as time travel...)